# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser is hazardous

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

```
 (declaration of 'com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Parser' appears in /data/data/probuff.cmcm.com.protobuftest/files/instant-run/dex/slice-protobuf-java-3.3.0_337abc31829bde926038696b7f238f11a5b7c8a2-classes.dex)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:296)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:289)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:418)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                                                   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                                                                                   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                   at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.<clinit>(UnknownFieldSet.java:1037)
                                                                                   at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.<init>(GeneratedMessageV3.java:88)
                                                                                   at mayday.Service$Location.<init>(Service.java:0)
                                                                                   at mayday.Service$Location.<clinit>(Service.java:7970)
                                                                                   at probuff.cmcm.com.protobuftest.MainActivity.testProbuf(MainActivity.java:21)
                                                                                   at probuff.cmcm.com.protobuftest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            testProbuf();


}
private void testProbuf(){
    Service.Location.Builder builder = Service.Location.newBuilder();
    builder.setAccuracy(1);
    builder.setProvider("apple");
    byte[] bytes= builder.build().toByteArray();
    try {
        Service.Location location=  Service.Location.parseFrom(bytes);
        System.out.println("test  accuracy="+location.getAccuracy()+" provider="+location.getProvider());
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

app build :

> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
>       compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.0'
>       compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.4.0'
>       compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.4.0'
>       compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.4.0' }

Comment: And the question is??? please, be more specific.. what you want to achieve, etc.. and watch the formatting..

Comment: i just want to sovle the crash , thanks

Comment: is this happening on debug? or when?

Comment: when  start the test app

Comment: when  excute the line :Service.Location.Builder builder = Service.Location.newBuilder();          the app crash

Comment: I understand that grpc already includes a newer version of protobuf (3.3.1), have you tried excluding it from the compiled package in your gradle? Or putting the same version?

Comment: better you provide the code of the new builder() or that builder class. From the first look it like you have not implemented the AbstractParser Correctly.

Comment: you are correct ,  i  remove grpc jars （   compie 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.4.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.4.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.4.0'）     ，the app is ok .    grpc jars and protobuf-java  clash .    thank you very mush !

Comment: @apple but anyways, if you need those packages, you can maybe just update the protobuf version to 3.3.1

Comment: @apple I added the comment as a proper answer. Im glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, I understand that grpc already includes a newer version of protobuf (3.3.1). So you should either try excluding the version of protobuf included in grpc using `exclude(module: 'com.google.protobuf')` in your gradle file, or you could increase your version to 3.3.1 in:

```
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.1'
```